# How can I integrate Spring Security with my already existing REST web services

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, authentication, spring-security

I have created REST web services using Spring & Hibernate. Now i want to integrate Spring security in my web services. How can I integrate, Whether i have to add authentication parameters (username, password) in the url's or is there any alternate way of integrating Spring Security without changing the urls. Thanks in  advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches to securing REST services based on nature of use, sensitivity of information exchanged, etc.  A general design assumption is that REST calls will be completely stateless, thereby obviating use of state-preservation stores like HTTP Session.

#### Option 1: Basic HTTP authentication

Clients could send username and password with every request using HTTP Basic Authentication.  This may be useful if the application is an Intranet application where the user.  You will have to write a component that checks each request for the credentials and denies those that are unauthenticated.

The downside is obviously that clients will have to be authenticated for every single request.  If you need to perform role checking as well, that too will then be tied to every single request.

---

#### Option 2: Credentials with every request

You could include user credentials with every request, but that would open your system up for attacks since the credentials will be clearly visible for GET requests.

---

#### Option 3: Token based authentication

Clients would authenticate themselves using a username and password over an HTTP POST request, in response to which they would receive a REST session token (similar in purpose to an HTTP session ID).  Then, the client would replay the token as an HTTP request header with every subsequent request.  The server would simply authenticate against this token.

The advantage is that the user needs to be authenticated only once.  If you need to perform role checks, you could create a lookup cache with the token as the key and the roles as the value.

---

You can see a sample application utilizing option 3 on [Github](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-security-rest).